# Can we change page headers on the basis of data range on a single sheet of excel?

Tags: excel

I have excel sheet having three data ranges for now. I want to print the header of each data range in case data gets over more than 1 page.
I am able to do it for one data range on one sheet, but when printing three data ranges from the same sheet, I get the header of the 1st data range repeated again but not of the 2nd data range.
**EXAMPLE**

> data1

Class1

id name class

1 A 2

2 B 2

3 C 3

...

...

100 BH 3

> data2

Class2

id name class

1 AZ 2

2 BD 2

3 CF 3

...

...

100 GH 3

Now I till the data1 section is on the page I want **Class1** as header and when data2 section is on the page I want **Class2** as header.