# Concatenate if, in a range

Tags: excel, concatenation

I'm having a issue to get a text result which is a concatenate/join of "X" cells of a column based quantity in another cell. Example:

```
Cell value = 2

Name  
Txt1         
Txt2         
Txt3          
Txt4          

Result = Txt1Txt2

Cell value = 3

Name  
Txt1         
Txt2         
Txt3          
Txt4          

Result = Txt1Txt2Txt3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One must have [`CONCAT()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/concat-function-9b1a9a3f-94ff-41af-9736-694cbd6b4ca2):

```
=CONCAT(A2:INDEX(A2:A5,C1))
```

[image]

---

If one does not have CONCAT this UDF will mimic the function.  Put this in a module attached to the workbook:

```
Function CONCAT(rng As Range)
    Dim rngArr As Variant
    rngArr = rng

    On Error GoTo onlyone
    Dim itm As Variant
    For Each itm In rngArr
        CONCAT = CONCAT & itm
    Next itm
    Exit Function
onlyone:
        CONCAT = rngArr
End Function
```

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner, can you please suggest me on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60994026/9508662

Comment: @ArooshRana that has to do with printing and I do not have a clue how to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, this help me a lot. :D